# Ajax.BeginForm not creating a form tag inside the dom

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In my MVC project I'm using an ajax form to dynamically update some search results based on a modified search term.

When rendering the `Ajax.BeginForm()` Method, it doesn't render a `<form>` tag on the page (in the DOM)

everything is set up fine, Jquery, Unobtrusive and AJAX are all referenced and I have working `Ajax.BeginForm` instances elsewhere

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FilterSearch","Attachment", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        OnComplete = "updateSearchResults",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    },new{}))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContactId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OpportunityId)


        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchTerm, new { placeholder = "Search Term", @class = "header-search-box" })
        <input type="submit" class="header-search-input" />
    }
```

is just rendering inside the DOM as

```
<input id="AccountId" name="AccountId" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="ContactId" name="ContactId" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="OpportunityId" name="OpportunityId" type="hidden" value="O6UJ9A001TB1">
<input class="header-search-box" id="SearchTerm" name="SearchTerm" placeholder="Search Term" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" class="header-search-input">
```

Comment: Do you have malformed HTML somewhere in your project? Also, are you inspecting this via a DOM debugger (like Chrome's inspect) or via view-source? If there's any kind of begin/end tag inconsistency, Chrome (and others) will not show the structure correctly (and, subsequently, lose various elements).

Comment: via the inspector as the page is loaded in itself via AJAX, no errors in the HTML, however. When loaded in its own page, it renders the Form tag

Comment: Is there a chance of a nested form? Long story short, `Ajax.BeginForm` outputs `<form>` regardless. The only thing I can think of is the post-processing (AJAX handler) is fouling it up ([un]justly).

Comment: it may well be a nested form - good idea, i'll check on that. Thanks

Comment: thats great, thanks for that tip. there was a form way up the page that was coming all the way down to the bottom unnecessarily. If you make an answer ill mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try (generally speaking):

1. Examine your source code (and not what the DOM is interpreting).

   - The DOM is based on how a browser/HTML parser interpreted the page, and now how it may actually be output. (Invalid markup will generally be suppressed, to the best of the parser's ability, and won't show up in debug tools, but will still sit on the page).
2. Confirm you don't have any markup mis-aligned.

   - Razor is smart enough to detect invalid markup, and may be cleansing output (and fixing a potential mistake), but not in a manner you were expecting.
3. Given this is dynamic content, make sure you're not nesting forms.

   - `Ajax.BeginForm` (and the other form helpers) supply `<form>`/`</form>` tags regardless; It's in the ctor/de-ctor methods to output those tags.
   - Some kind of post-processing (on the side of the AJAX processor) may be "cleansing" the output to avoid invalid HTML (e.g nested form tags). If it sees there's already a `<form>`, it may strip that tag from any supplemental markup being brought in.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a form inside another form. Check your parent views to make sure you haven't accidentally started a form, and then included this partial page.

(Thanks for the tip @LiamHT)